# iOS Parse Push: development and production environment

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, development-environment, production-environment

For my app, I created two apps in Parse: one for development environment (with the related developer certificate for push notifications) and one for production (with the related distribution certificate). Everything worked fine in development environment, and after switching the app to production everything works fine too. The problem is that now, even if I change they key for Parse (client and app key) back to development (the 1st app), the app is stuck in distribution (the 2nd app). I keep receiving the notifications sent to the production app (the 2nd app) and I do not receive at all the one sent to the development app (the 1st app).

I thought of using just a single app and uploading both the certificates and using the switch “production”, but:
i) I do not know if that switch works properly and select the appropriate push certificate;
ii) I would not be able anyway to go back to development after going into production.

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Two different applications on Parse have to be created, with different bundle ID, in order to be able to have both development and production environments on the same device and still receive push notifications on both of them.

This is the [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/parse-developers/xcnng2ti_z4/cWW_NtQIMC4J) I got from an engineer from Parse:

> Have you ever had ParseAppA installed on your device? We're getting
>   into APNS territory here but maybe the devicetoken generated when you
>   installed ParseAppA is still valid for this bundle id and that's why
>   you still get the push.
>
> In my own projects I avoid a set up like yours, and prefer either
>   using distribution profiles exclusively, or using different bundle ids
>   to separate both apps clearly. Reusing the same bundle id here just
>   makes it harder to debug push on iOS.
>
> The development/production switch for your Parse app does not affect
>   push. If a Parse app has a mix of production and development
>   certificates, Parse will first use the production certificate and fall
>   back to the development certificate. Are you using different bundle
>   ids for each of your apps? This would allow you to explicitly target
>   one or the other.